# php include files for multiple fields (build framework)

Tags: php, frameworks, include, custom-fields

I created a framework to dynamically generate fields and I want to organize these fields by separated them in files.

Currently I've got a switch statement like this:

```
case 'text':
    echo '<td><input class="input-txt" type="text" name="meta['. $field['id'] .']" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" /></td>';
    break;
case 'textarea':
    echo '<td><textarea class="input-txtarea" name="meta['. $field['id'] .']" id="', $field['id'], '" rows="8">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea></td>';
    break;`
```

I want to include all fields in separated php files like this:

```
include_once('./text-field.php');
include_once('./textarea-field.php');
```

What is the right way to implement and pass arguments in this switch statement if I include fields in separated files.

What is the right way to build a framework like this? I need some advises to correctly create my framework.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
**text-field.php**
<?php 
  echo '<input type="text" name="$_GET['arg']">';
?>
```

now in your switch statment

```
case 'text':
    echo file_get_contents('text-field.php?arg=1');
    break;
```

For making controls a pseudo code.

```
class Form {

public static function text($name, $default, $additional = array(), )
{
   echo '<input type = "text" name= "$name" class="$additional['class']" value= "$default">';
}

}

Form::text('first_name' , $first_name, array('class' => 'form-control'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I mean more like a construct function or something like this. To keep argument with php file and to avoid maybe a switch statement with tones of cases.

Comment: How you architect can be of various ways but for sending arguments i've updated my answer

Comment: "What is the right way to build a framework like this? I need some advises to correctly create my framework." This is too broad i guess.

Comment: I mean, I looked at some framework and there is a folder that contains all fields separated in php files. And they include them and generate fields like this. I want to understand what is the way to do that. They don't use switch cas to make it works. It seems better organize and more efficient for huge amount of fields type.